# Encoding 3 values to [0,1,-1]

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a column in a dataframe `size`:

```
   size
  --------
    big
    normal
    small
```

I want to mal the values like this:

```
big == 1
normal == -1
small == 0
```

I can run `apply(lambda x: 1 if x=='big' else -1)`  but I dont know to use it with 3 values.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Use `map` by dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
apply(lambda x: {'big': 1, 'normal': -1, 'small': 0}[x])
```